# Do color dyes give specific properties?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I go to purchase a color dye, in the detail section of the color dye there is stuff written like "This pigment boost speeds" etc.
Do color dyes really have any impact on the character properties (other than appearance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dyes only change the aesthetic look of your character.

That said, there are achievements directly linked to having a full set of certain colours equipped, and taking out certain bosses.

Comment: @Rusty I presume the achievements were something that interests you, regardless of not being a "player property". If you would like, I'm happy to edit my answer to detail the achievements effected by ink, but I would have to edit your question to incorporate 'all game benefits', instead of just 'player properties'. Once you have a tiny bit more red (50), you will be able to comment and confirm if that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Dyes only change the color of a piece of armor. The text in the detail section is just flavor.

Answer (score -2):

### They are not supposed to.

Aside from ripping open the code, there's no way to be sure a rogue coder didn't put some tiny modifier for the lulz, but officially they have no effect.

There are however two achievements tied to dyes :

- Pink'd requires you to kill a number of bosses in all Lovely-dyed armor
- I just blue myself is another boss hit list to be done in Mariner-dyed armor.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it contains speculation. Please consider revising your answer.

Comment: Ha. Haha. Hahahahaha. HAHAHAAAHAHAHAHA !!!